# Как сделать "Рестарт" для кнопок разом?

Tags: java, swing

Разрабатываю игру в качестве обучения. Вся игра идет через кнопки. Играбельные кнопки у меня занесены в список:

```
static ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

Так вот, после игры хочу нажать на кнопку "рестарт" и играть заново.
Я знаю, как сделать рестарт для каждой кнопки отдельно, но какой способ есть для рестарта всех кнопок разом?

Нашел такой способ:

```java
fileMenu = new JMenu("Файл");
resItem = new JMenuItem("Рестарт");
fileMenu.add(resItem);
resItem.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    for (JButton button : buttons) {
        button.setText("");
        button.setSelected(false);
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
    resultat.setText("Сейчас начинается ваш ход!");
});
```

И при запуске рестарта да, все вроде бы очистилось, но при нажатии на какую-либо из кнопок происходит сразу же победа игрока! Как правильно реализовать кнопку рестарта играбельных кнопок разом? Буду благодарен.

Полный код:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTakToe {

    //Создание фрейма, шрифта, кнопок (3х3) и текстового поля
    JFrame frame;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    Font font = new Font("sanserif", Font.BOLD, 55);
    static JButton button1 = new JButton();
    static JButton button2 = new JButton();
    static JButton button3 = new JButton();
    static JButton button4 = new JButton();
    static JButton button5 = new JButton();
    static JButton button6 = new JButton();
    static JButton button7 = new JButton();
    static JButton button8 = new JButton();
    static JButton button9 = new JButton();
    // Текстовое поле для вывода результата
    static JTextField resultat = new JTextField();
    // Массив для хранения кнопок
    static ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    // Список всех ходов игрока и компьютера
    static ArrayList<Integer> Moves = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // Отдельный поток для хода компьютера
    static Thread c;
    // Массив для хода игрока
    static int [][] player;
    static int[][] comp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTakToe().gui();
        player = new int[3][3];
        comp = new int[3][3];
        c = new Thread(new CompPlayer());

    }

    public void gui() {
        // Добавление кнопок, текстового поля для вывода результата
        //функция остановки компилятора при закрытии программы
        frame = new JFrame("Крестики-нолики");
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Файл");
         JMenuItem resItem = new JMenuItem("Рестарт");
        fileMenu.add(resItem);
        resItem.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            button.setText("");
            button.setSelected(false);
            button.setEnabled(true);
          }
        });
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Выход");
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);
        exitItem.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            System.exit(0);           
        });
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
        button1.setActionCommand("1");
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button1);
        mainPanel.add(button1);
        button2.setActionCommand("2");
        button2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button2);
        mainPanel.add(button2);
        button3.setActionCommand("3");
        button3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button3);
        mainPanel.add(button3);
        button4.setActionCommand("4");
        button4.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button4);
        mainPanel.add(button4);
        button5.setActionCommand("5");
        button5.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button5);
        mainPanel.add(button5);
        button6.setActionCommand("6");
        button6.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button6);
        mainPanel.add(button6);
        button7.setActionCommand("7");
        button7.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button7);
        mainPanel.add(button7);
        button8.setActionCommand("8");
        button8.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button8);
        mainPanel.add(button8);
        button9.setActionCommand("9");
        button9.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttons.add(button9);
        mainPanel.add(button9);
        resultat.setText("Сейчас начинается ваш ход!");
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, resultat);
        frame.setSize(300,350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //Остановить компилятор при закрытии программы
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    // Все ходы игрока и компьютера
    static int allMoves = 0;
    // Счетчик на количество хода игрока 
    int allMovesPlayer = 0;
    int allMovesComp = 0;
    // Функция увеличения кол-ва всех ходов
    public synchronized static void growAllMoves() {
        allMoves = allMoves + 1;
    }
    // Функция получения кол-ва ходов
    public synchronized static int getAllMoves() {
        return allMoves;
    }
    // Добавление к значению хода участника игры
    public synchronized static void add (int c) {
        Moves.add(c);
    }
    // Статус игрока (1 победа, 0 продолжение игры)
    int statPlayer = 0;
    int statComp = 0;

    // Хранит значение хода компьютера
    static int compMove;

    // Команды для кнопок (игрок)
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // Вызов метода увеличивания ходов
            growAllMoves();
            // Определяем какую кнопку нажал игрок
            int actionCommand = Integer.parseInt(event.getActionCommand());
            if (getAllMoves() % 2 != 0) {
                allMovesPlayer++;
                switch (actionCommand) {
                    case 1: {
                        player[0][0] = 1;
                        button1.setFont(font);
                        button1.setText("X");
                        button1.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        player[0][1] = 1;
                        button2.setFont(font);
                        button2.setText("X");
                        button2.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        player[0][2] = 1;
                        button3.setFont(font);
                        button3.setText("X");
                        button3.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4: {
                        player[1][0] = 1;
                        button4.setFont(font);
                        button4.setText("X");
                        button4.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 5: {
                        player[1][1] = 1;
                        button5.setFont(font);
                        button5.setText("X");
                        button5.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 6: {
                        player[1][2] = 1;
                        button6.setFont(font);
                        button6.setText("X");
                        button6.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 7:{
                        player[2][0] = 1;
                        button7.setFont(font);
                        button7.setText("X");
                        button7.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 8: {
                        player[2][1] = 1;
                        button8.setFont(font);
                        button8.setText("X");
                        button8.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 9: {
                        player[2][2] = 1;
                        button9.setFont(font);
                        button9.setText("X");
                        button9.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Добавление хода игрока в общий список ходов
                // Также проводим проверку: 
                // при ходах игрока больше 3 проверяем, выиграл он или нет.
                add(actionCommand);
                if (allMovesPlayer >= 3) {
                    if (statPlayer == 0) {
                        statPlayer = check(player);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Если игрок не выиграл, но при этом его кол-ва хода
            // меньше 5, то запускается ход компьютера
            if (statPlayer == 0 && allMovesPlayer < 5)c.run();
            // В случае победы
            if (statPlayer == 1) {
                resultat.setText("Поздравляем игрок! Ты выиграл!!!");
                for (JButton b : buttons) {
                    b.setEnabled(false);
                }
                // Боевая ничья
            } else if (statPlayer == 0 && allMovesPlayer >=5) {
                resultat.setText("Боевая ничья! Спасибо за игру :)");
                for (JButton b : buttons) {
                    b.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // Проверка комбинации на выигрыш
    // в случае выигрыша возвращается 1
    public int check(int[][] a) {
        // Счетчики комбинаций
        //строка, столбец, 1 диагональ, 2 диагональ
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        int diagonal = 0;
        int diagonal2 = 0;
        // Проверки:
        // по строке или столбцу
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] == 1) row++;
                if (a[j][i] == 1) column++;
            }
            if (row == 3 || column == 3) {
                return 1;
            }
            row = 0;
            column = 0;
        }
        // диагональ 1
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length ; i++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 1) diagonal++;
            j++;
        }
        if (diagonal == 3) {
            return 1;
        }
        // диагональ 2
        for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < a.length ; i++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 1) diagonal2++;
            j--;
        }
        if (diagonal2 == 3) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
// Ход компьютера (четный)
class CompPlayer extends TicTakToe implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    growAllMoves();
        if (getAllMoves() % 2 == 0) {
            allMovesComp++;
            compMove =(int) (Math.random()*10);
            while(compMove == 0 || Moves.contains(compMove)) {
                if (allMovesComp >=5) break;
                compMove =(int) (Math.random()*10);
            }
            add(compMove);
           switch (compMove) {
                case 1: {
                    comp[0][0] = 1;
                    button1.setFont(font);
                    button1.setText("O");
                    button1.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    comp[0][1] = 1;
                    button2.setFont(font);
                    button2.setText("O");
                    button2.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    comp[0][2] = 1;
                    button3.setFont(font);
                    button3.setText("O");
                    button3.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    comp[1][0] = 1;
                    button4.setFont(font);
                    button4.setText("O");
                    button4.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    comp[1][1] = 1;
                    button5.setFont(font);
                    button5.setText("O");
                    button5.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    comp[1][2] = 1;
                    button6.setFont(font);
                    button6.setText("O");
                    button6.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 7:{
                    comp[2][0] = 1;
                    button7.setFont(font);
                    button7.setText("O");
                    button7.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 8: {
                    comp[2][1] = 1;
                    button8.setFont(font);
                    button8.setText("O");
                    button8.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 9: {
                    comp[2][2] = 1;
                    button9.setFont(font);
                    button9.setText("O");
                    button9.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }

            }
            // При кол-ве ходов компьютера больше 3
            // делаем проверку на выигрыш
            if (allMovesComp >= 3) {
                if (statComp == 0) {
                    statComp = check(comp);
                }
            }
        }
        // Сообщение для игрока
        if (statComp == 1) {
            resultat.setText("Вы проиграли!");
            buttons.forEach((b) -> {
                b.setEnabled(false);
        });
        } else if (statComp == 0 && allMovesComp >=5) {
            resultat.setText("Боевая ничья! Спасибо за игру :)");
            buttons.forEach((b) -> {
                b.setEnabled(false);
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мало кода, чтобы ответить, точнее проблема не в приведенном фрагменте, покажите какие слушатели висят а кнопках..

Comment: все добавил....

Comment: Просто жесть. То есть если событий и кнопок будет 1000 вы будете 1000 кейсов делать?

Comment: вот я и хочу узнать как сделать все разом и понять, где допустил ошибку

Answer (score 0):

я решаю эту проблему, создавая метод reset(), в котором просто прописаны все изначальные параметры, необходимые для сброса н-р:

```
`
gameWin = false;
selectButton = false;
int ae = 0;
`
```

обнулить двумерный массив через fori

вызываешь метод reset(); и игра сбрасывается, все просто